# Comments and questions as answers

Tags: discussion

In my review queue, I have been seeing a lot of questions and comments put as answers. How can we make it clear were these things should go?

Comment: Rather than engaging in an emotional to and fro with other users, please just flag them and move on.

Comment: @dmckee I have flagged him. This is not even his 3rd time doing it, however. I think that there needs to be a better way to explain it.

Comment: There are provisions in place for really persistent abusers. In principle the mods could contact or suspend the user and there are automated responses.

Comment: I should say that DavidZ and I have both been on low duty factor lately due to interference from "real" life, so flag handling has suffered a bit. But it will all get dealt with.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a good way to do it. All we can really do to *prevent* "mis-posting" is expose new members to instructions telling them what should and shouldn't be posted as an answer, but most of them aren't going to read instructions. I think the best we can do in practice is stay on top of the moderation: watch out for non-answers in the queues and while browsing questions, and flag them as such.